# React JS: Populating a rsuite dropdown from a json object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm have this component using the rsuite ui  dropdown component  [here is the Component Docs](https://rsuitejs.com/en/components/select-picker/#%3CSelectPicker%3E) that should populate its elements from the json held in the component state but i keep getting this error any time i try clicking on either of the drop downs.

> ERROR:
>   VM7492:37 Warning: React DevTools encountered an error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
>       --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
>       |     property '_context' -> object with constructor 'Object'
>       --- property 'Provider' closes the circle

the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {SelectPicker } from 'rsuite';

class TimeSelector extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      start_time: [
             {"start_hour":"12:00 AM","start_id":"am-0"},
             {"start_hour":"01:00 AM","start_id":"am-1"},
             {"start_hour":"02:00 AM","start_id":"am-2"},
             {"start_hour":"03:00 AM","start_id":"am-3"},
             {"start_hour":"04:00 AM","start_id":"am-4"},
             {"start_hour":"05:00 AM","start_id":"am-5"},
             {"start_hour":"06:00 AM","start_id":"am-6"},
             {"start_hour":"07:00 AM","start_id":"am-7"},
             {"start_hour":"08:00 AM","start_id":"am-8"},
             {"start_hour":"09:00 AM","start_id":"am-9"},
             {"start_hour":"10:00 AM","start_id":"am-10"},
             {"start_hour":"11:00 AM","start_id":"am-11"},
             {"start_hour":"12:00 PM","start_id":"pm-0"},
             {"start_hour":"1:00 PM","start_id":"pm-1"},
             {"start_hour":"2:00 PM","start_id":"pm-2"},
             {"start_hour":"3:00 PM","start_id":"pm-3"},
             {"start_hour":"4:00 PM","start_id":"pm-4"},
             {"start_hour":"5:00 PM","start_id":"pm-5"},
             {"start_hour":"6:00 PM","start_id":"pm-6"},
             {"start_hour":"7:00 PM","start_id":"pm-7"},
             {"start_hour":"8:00 PM","start_id":"pm-8"},
             {"start_hour":"9:00 PM","start_id":"pm-9"},
             {"start_hour":"10:00 PM","start_id":"pm-10"},
             {"start_hour":"11:00 PM","start_id":"pm-11"},
             {"start_hour":"12:00 PM","start_id":"pm-12"}
      ],
      end_time:[
              {"end_hour":"12:00 AM","end_id":"am-0"},
              {"end_hour":"01:00 AM","end_id":"am-2"},
              {"end_hour":"02:00 AM","end_id":"am-3"},
              {"end_hour":"03:00 AM","end_id":"am-4"},
              {"end_hour":"04:00 AM","end_id":"am-5"},
              {"end_hour":"05:00 AM","end_id":"am-5"},
              {"end_hour":"06:00 AM","end_id":"am-6"},
              {"end_hour":"07:00 AM","end_id":"am-7"},
              {"end_hour":"08:00 AM","end_id":"am-8"},
              {"end_hour":"09:00 AM","end_id":"am-9"},
              {"end_hour":"10:00 AM","end_id":"am-10"},
              {"end_hour":"11:00 AM","end_id":"am-11"},
              {"end_hour":"12:00 PM","end_id":"pm-0"},
              {"end_hour":"1:00 PM","end_id":"pm-1"},
              {"end_hour":"2:00 PM","end_id":"pm-2"},
              {"end_hour":"3:00 PM","end_id":"pm-3"},
              {"end_hour":"4:00 PM","end_id":"pm-4"},
              {"end_hour":"5:00 PM","end_id":"pm-5"},
              {"end_hour":"6:00 PM","end_id":"pm-6"},
              {"end_hour":"7:00 PM","end_id":"pm-7"},
              {"end_hour":"8:00 PM","end_id":"pm-8"},
              {"end_hour":"9:00 PM","end_id":"pm-9"},
              {"end_hour":"10:00 PM","end_id":"pm-10"},
              {"end_hour":"11:00 PM","end_id":"pm-11"},
              {"end_hour":"12:00 PM","end_id":"pm-12"}
      ],  
      selectedStartTime:'',
      selectedEndTime:'',
    };


  }

  render() {

    return (
        <div>
            Start Time:
            <SelectPicker
                toggleComponentClass={Button}
                size="md"
                placeholder="12:00 AM"
                data={this.state.start_time}
                labelKey="start_hour"
                valueKey="start_id"
            />
            End Time:
            <SelectPicker
                toggleComponentClass={Button}
                size="md"
                placeholder={this.state.end_time[0].end_hour}
                data={this.state.end_time}
                labelKey="end_hour"
                valueKey="end_id"
            />    
        </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {

  }

}

export default TimeSelector;
```

i have checked the json object seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are not passing the `data` right way. It should be `DataItemType` array which contains:

```
type DataItemType = {
  value: string; // property value is the value of valueKey 
  label: React.Node; // property value is the vaue of labelKey
  children?: Array<DataItemType>; // property value is the value of childrenKey
  groupBy?: string;
};
```

You can try passing this:

```
data = [
   {label:"12:00 AM", value:"am-0"},
   {label:"01:00 AM", value:"am-1"},
   {label:"02:00 AM", value:"am-2"},
]
```

Hope this work's for you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Muhammad Zeeshan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60227233/2050629) answer: You need to transform the data so that it matches the required data format.

For start time:

```
data={this.state.start_time.map(entry => ({
  label: entry.start_hour,
  value: entry.start_id,
})}
```

and for your end time:

```
data={this.state.end_time.map(entry => ({
  label: entry.end_hour,
  value: entry.end_id,
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case what happened to me was that I wanted to bring the data from an API and I got the same error. The specific solution tells you the same TypeScript :) you just have to put a typing to the property that you send to the **Autocomplete** here I show you my code

```
type DataItemType = {
    label: string; 
};


export const useGetCityApi = () => {

    const [city, setCity] = useState<DataItemType[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getCitysApi.get<GetCityAPIType>('/locations?term=PRG&location_types=airport')
                   .then( resp =>{
                      setCity([{
                          label:resp.data.locations[0].city.name  
                      }]);
                   })
                   .catch(console.log); 
    }, [])    

    return city;
}
```

You see how after I introduce a specific DataItemType type in useState I indicate the type of data to handle that hook. In another component, I assign the return to a variable and add it to the Autocomplete